# react date picker does not show up when clicked, takes certain space

Tags: datepicker, reactjs

I am having a problem to implement date picker in react js. I need a `date picker` such that user can navigate through different years easily.

For this, I am testing this [A carefully crafted date picker for React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker) date picker. The problem is that, it needs much space for a single date picker. I have to use several date pickers in the form. I want that date picker input will be like a text box input. When I click on the text box, date picker will appear, [like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker).

I have included the following **two css files** in my project.

1. [react-date-picker/index.css](https://github.com/zippyui/react-date-picker/blob/master/index.css)
2. [react-date-picker/base.css](https://github.com/zippyui/react-date-picker/blob/master/base.css)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is DateField. Try this instead:

```
<DateField
        defaultValue={"30.05.2016"}
        dateFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"
/>
```